# Ошибка: request for member begin in ..., which is of non-class type

Tags: c++

Объясните ошибку

```
vector<string> vecquest();

for(vector<string>::iterator i=vecquest.begin();i!=vecquest.end();++i)
{
    cout <<*i<<" "<<endl;
}
```

Ошибка

> `request for member begin in vecquest, which is of non-class type 'std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > ()()'`

Comment: @Suren, покажите объявление объекта `vecquest`

Comment: @Suren, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: как понять 101010 редактор

Comment: @Suren под вопросом есть кнопка "Править". В открывшемся редакторе есть кнопка 101010, позволяющая отформатировать код.

Comment: А зачем скобки в объявлении vecquest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исправил Ваш код:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    using std::vector;
    using std::string;
    vector<string> vecquest; // здесь лишние скобки
    std::ifstream filequest("questions_.txt");    
    string k;
    while (getline (filequest, k) )
    {
        vecquest.push_back(k); // и здесь тоже
    }
    for(vector<string>::iterator i = vecquest.begin(); i != vecquest.end(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << *i <<"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: @Suren нажмите на галочку рядом с вопросом, чтобы принять ответ